# r package for fuzzy sums of multiple rasters

Tags: sum, raster, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I would like to do a fuzzy sum with raster data in r to form a cumulative resistance layer for research. I have found packages and functions to do fuzzy sums with vector data and was wondering if anyone can share resources for specifically combining raster layers with fuzzy logic.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spatialEco::fuzzySum` for both vector and raster data.

For example for three terra rasters: `rast1`, `rast2`, `rast3` it would work as follows:

```
rFuzzySum <- spatialEco::fuzzySum(c(rast1, rast2, rast3))
```

If you write it open, it would be:

```
rFuzzySum <- (1 - ( (1 - rast1) * 
                    (1 - rast2) *
                    (1 - rast3) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an illustration of how you can do that, using the suggestions by MattKummu

Example data

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
x <- x / max(minmax(x))
```

Two approaches

```
a <- 1 - prod(1 - x)
b <- spatialEco::fuzzySum(x)
```